# Runlength Encoding Algorithm[Data Compression]

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement the algorithm RLE with simple input like:

```
ddddddddddhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhttttttttttttt
```

code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<char> read;

    ifstream file;
    file.open("file.txt");

    if (!file) {
        cout << "Unable to open";
    }

    char v;

    while(file>>v) {
        read.push_back(v);
    }

    char x;
    int count=0;

    for(int i=0; i<read.size(); i++) {

        x = read[i];

        if(x != read[++i]) {
          cout << x << "1";
        }

        while(x == read[++i]) {
            count++;
        }
        cout << x << count;

        count = 0;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting is:

```
d9d1h12h1t10t1
```

Please help me with the code.

**Update:** I have updated the question as I have realized few things.

**Plus:** This code produced no output, is there anything wrong which I am doing wrong?

```
char o;
char n; 
int count=0; 

for(int i=0; i<read.size(); i++) { 

   o = read[i]; 
   n = read[++i]; 
while(o == n) { 
      count++; 
} 

   cout << o << count; 

      if(o != n) { 
           cout << o << "1"; 
      } count = 0; 
} 
return 0;
```

Comment: The right ways to fix this are either a) learn to use the single-step feature of your debugger and watch what is happening or b) "run" the code on a sheet of paper and see what is happening.  "Learn to fish" and you'll be fed with good code for a lifetime.

Comment: char will hold all ascii values, but not the extended Unicode characters. It will also hold values -128 to 127 if signed, 0, to 255 if unsigned, which can be used for run length encoding systems.

Answer (score 1):

This loop:

```
char x;
int count=0;

for(int i=0; i<read.size(); i++) {

    int j=i;
    x = read[i];

    if(x != read[++j]) {
      cout << x << "1";
    }

    while(x == read[++j]) {
        count++;
    }
    cout << x << count;
}
```

Has several errors. First, you should use two indices, `i` and `j`. `i` is going through each element of `read`, but then `j` is iterating through a subsequence too. What you want is to go through each element only once, and in each case either print or increase the count. However having a for loop and moving the index inside too is not a very good practice, is rather error-prone. Also you have to `cout` statements that are do not run at the right time (you don't wan to print something on every iteration, only when the character changes). You could do it with a while loop, or using a simpler structure like:

```
// If there are no characters finish
if (read.empty()) {
    return 0;
}
// Get the first character
char lastChar = read[0];
int count = 1;  //  We have counted one character for now
// Go through each character (note start from 1 instead of 0)
for(int i = 1; i < read.size(); i++) {
    // Get the next char
    char newChar = read[i];
    // If it is different, print the current count and reset the counter
    if (lastChar != newChar) {
        cout << lastChar << count;
        count = 1;
        lastChar = newChar;
    } else {  // Else increase the counter
        count++;
    }
}
// Print the last one
cout << lastChar << count;

return 0;
```

Comment: How about this??


char o; char n; int count=0; for(int i=0; i<read.size(); i++) { o = read[i]; n = read[++i]; while(o == n) { count++; } cout << o << count; if(o != n) { cout << o << "1"; } count = 0; } return 0;